# The estimate of real and imaginary part of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic in the unit disk $D(0,1)$, and $f(0)=0$. Suppose $|\Re f(z)|\leq 1$ for all $|z|<1$. Show that 
$$|\Re f(z)|\leq\frac{4}{\pi}\arctan|z|;$$
$$|\Im f(z)|\leq \frac{2}{\pi}\ln\frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}.$$

What I could do is just to observe that
$$\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}f(z)}-1}{e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}f(z)}+1}:D(0,1)\to D(0,1)$$ with $0$ being fixed. And Schwarz lemma applies. However, I could not get any information on the real and imaginary part of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have by the Schwarz lemma is

$$\left\lvert \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}f(z)\right)\right\rvert \leqslant \lvert z\rvert.$$

Writing $w = h(z) = \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{4}f(z)\right)$, what you want is

$$\bigl\lvert \Re \arctan w\bigr\rvert \leqslant \arctan \lvert w\rvert\tag{1}.$$

Since $\lvert w\rvert \leqslant \lvert z\rvert$, by the monotonicity of the real arcus tangent, the bound for $\Re f$ follows from $(1)$. The most difficult part is seeing that $(1)$ is what you need.

To obtain $(1)$, we look at the explicit formula for $\arctan$,

$$\arctan w = \frac{1}{2i} \log \frac{1+iw}{1-iw}.\tag{2}$$

The real part of $\arctan w$ is thus half the argument of $\frac{1+iw}{1-iw}$, and to achieve $(1)$, we must see what the maximal argument of that is on the circle $\lvert w\rvert = r < 1$. Just plugging a few points of the circle into the Möbius transformation shows that the image of $\lvert w\rvert = r$ is

$$\left\lvert \zeta - \frac{1+r^2}{1-r^2}\right\rvert = \frac{2r}{1-r^2},$$

and that circle intersects the unit circle at right angles, so the maximal argument is

$$\arctan \frac{2r}{1-r^2} = \arctan \left(\tan (2\arctan r)\right) = 2\arctan r,$$

which by symmetry (with respect to conjugation) is just $(1)$. So we have seen

$$\left\lvert \Re \left(\frac{\pi}{4}f(z)\right)\right\rvert \leqslant \arctan \left\lvert \tan\left( \frac{\pi}{4}f(z)\right)\right\rvert \leqslant \arctan \lvert z\rvert.$$

Multiply with $\frac{4}{\pi}$ to get the listed form.

The bound for the imaginary part is quite analogous to obtain, one needs the maximal modulus of

$$\frac{1+iw}{1-iw}$$

on $\lvert w\rvert = r$. I leave that to the reader.

Comment: Since image of $|w|=r$ under Mobius transformation  $T(w)= \dfrac{1+iw}{1-iw}$ is a circle, why isn't $\text{max}_{|w|=r} \text{arg} T(w)=2\pi \ ?$

Comment: Because that circle lies in the right half-plane, it doesn't enclose $0$. And we use the principal value of the argument, with values in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I want a person who is an expert in complex analysis for solving this problem. when I search under complex analysis tag, you are the top user of all time. Therefore I'm sure you can help me for this. Thank you for your attention on this problem. math.stackexchange.com/questions/987142/…

Comment: @DanielFischer: May I know why $2\text{arctan}r= \text{arctan} \dfrac{2r}{1-r^2} \ ?$

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo Since $\tan (2x) = \frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2 x}$, setting $x = \arctan r$ we obtain $\tan (2\arctan r) = \frac{2r}{1-r^2}$. Apply $\arctan$ to that.